# How to skip field if Gson serialization failed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

For example, server response#1 has `name` Object:

```
     {
       "id":"vfa45f42", 
       "name": { 
                "firstName":"UserFirstName",
                "lastName":"UserLastName"
         }
    }
```

But sometimes server response#2 has `name` String for other objects of user(that's because server has MongoDB, and at v1 it was `String`, but at v2 it is `Object`):

```
    {
        "id":"abfaf453", 
        "name":"OneSentenceUserName"
    }
```

So, if I make with response#2 this:

```
val type = object : TypeToken<User>() {}.type
gson.fromJson(responseString, type)
```

where

```
data class User(val id:String, val name: Name)

data class Name(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

Error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line ...
```

I expected to make `name = null` if it's `String` at json

Comment: I have been through this, and belive me there is no solution for this from GSON guys. Good luck though

Comment: why don't you check the type of name either it is a valid JSON object or string and then based on that pass value to store and use it?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your actual classes `User` and `Name`, you can create a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.htmlhttps://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) and create a full `Name` out of the single `name` string or the complete JSON object by reading it yourself.

```
class NameAdapter : TypeAdapter<Name>() {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(reader: JsonReader): Name? {
        return when(reader.peek()) {
            // if { "name": null }
            JsonToken.NULL -> {
                reader.nextNull()
                null
            }
            // if { "name": "SomeString" }
            JsonToken.STRING -> {
                Name(reader.nextString(), "")
            }
            //if { "name": { "firstName": "some", "lastName": "thing" }
            JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT -> {
                var firstName = ""
                var lastName = ""

                reader.beginObject()
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    val peek = reader.peek()
                    if(peek == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) break
                    else if(peek == JsonToken.NAME) {
                        when(reader.nextName()) {
                            // it will produce an exception if it isn't a string
                            "firstName" -> firstName = reader.nextString()
                            "lastName" -> lastName = reader.nextString()
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.endObject()
                Name(firstName, lastName)
            }
            else -> throw IOException("Unable to parse a name")
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: Name?) {
        if(value == null) {
            writer.nullValue()
            return
        }
        writer.beginObject()
        writer.name("firstName")
        writer.value(value.firstName)
        writer.name("lastName")
        writer.value(value.lastName)
        writer.endObject()
    }
}
```

Then you can add this type adapter to your gson builder.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Name::class.java, NameAdapter()).build()
```

It will deserialize correctly the name in each case and produce a full `Name` class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will help you directly, but for the same case I did the following with Kotlinx.Serializartion library:

Make name a JsonElement type

```
val name: JsonElement
```

Then create custom deserialization function like:

```
fun getName(): Name? =
    if (name is JsonObject) {
        // deserialize Name normally
    } else {
        // create Name by hand, only with 'name' property... 
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, just need to use one of these:

1.
First solution:

```
data class User(val id:String, @JsonAdapter(FailSafeNameTypeAdapter::class) val name: Name)
```

where

```
class FailSafeNameTypeAdapter internal constructor(private val delegate: TypeAdapter<Name>) : TypeAdapter<Name>() {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: Name?) {
        if (value == null) {
            writer.nullValue()
            return
        }

        // This catches non-proxied collections AND initialized proxied collections
        delegate.write(writer, value)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(reader: JsonReader): Name? {
        val peek = reader.peek()
        if (peek == STRING) {
            reader.skipValue()
            return null
        }
        return delegate.read(reader) as Name
    }

}
```

2. 

Second solution

```
data class User(val id:String, @JsonAdapter(FailSafePriceTypeAdapterFactory::class) val name: Name)
```

where

```
class FailSafePriceTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        if (Price::class.java.isAssignableFrom(type.rawType)) {
            val delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter<T>(this, type) as TypeAdapter<Price>

            return FailSafePriceTypeAdapter(delegate) as TypeAdapter<T>
        }

        return null
    }

    companion object {
        val FACTORY: TypeAdapterFactory = FailSafePriceTypeAdapterFactory()
    }
}
```

  3.

Third solution

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY)
            .apply {
                registerTypeAdapterFactory(FailSafePriceTypeAdapterFactory.FACTORY)

            }
            .create()
```